# Transposition with two variables: Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra

so I have a problem I can't seem to get my head around.

Solve for $a$ **not** $b$:

$$\dfrac{3a}{2} + \dfrac{2(b +3a)}{3} = -1$$

Just can't seem to get to the right answer, thank you community.

Comment: Show what you have done, so we can see where is your problem

Comment: 2b +6a/3 + 1 = -3a/2

then 2(2b+6a) + 1) = 3(3a) so

then 4b+12a + 2 = 9a

as far as i can get unfortunately

Comment: It's wrong! You have: $3a/2 +2b/3 +2a=-1$. Then sum the two monomials with $a$ and solve....

Comment: thank you for your help, i'm getting closer but still can't get to where i'm going ahh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{3a}{2}+\dfrac{2(b+3a)}{3}=-1 \iff\dfrac{3}{2}a+2a+\dfrac{2}{3}b=-1 \iff \dfrac{7}{2}a=-1-\dfrac{2}{3}b
$$
solve for $a$:
$$
a=\dfrac{2}{7}\left(-1-\dfrac{2}{3}b\right)
$$
If you want $a \ne b$ solve for $b$ the equation:
$$
\dfrac{2}{7}\left(-1-\dfrac{2}{3}b\right)=b
$$
and reject the solution.

Comment: thank you for your help so much, is there anyway to simplfy 'a' any further?

Comment: Doing multiplication you have $a=-2/7 -4b/21$. Don't forget to accept, if you like :-)

Answer (score 0):

$a=-\cfrac{5\cdot b}{10.5}$

Is the answer, the solution above is not really a solution since they haven't simplified.

Comment: This already has an accepted answer. Have you contributed something new ?